# How to create axios interceptors in a separate file in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, axios, interceptor

I would like to put my interceptors in a separate file instead of the default App.js so it's easier to manage and so I can keep my App.js file cleaner.
However I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

In your separate file, you will have to import your axios instance from the App.js file. You should already have created an axios instance and set it to be an export. From then on you can port over your interceptor code to the new file.

Example:

```
import { instance } from 'App.js';

// Add a request interceptor
instance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

// Add a response interceptor
instance.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```